# Page not found (404) Request Method: POST Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/reg_done

Tags: django, forms

```
        from django.contrib import admin
        from django.urls import path
        from . import views
        
        urlpatterns = [
            path('', views.Index, name='Index'),
            path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
            path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
            path('register/reg_done/', views.reg_done,),
            ]
```

Above is my urls.py. What I am trying is to get my reg_done page come up as after a user click on the submit button to save the regestration info. But its showing that this page not found.

I tried to change the path in form action as register/reg_done/. But then it showed the same error with register/register/reg_done.

In HTML I am giving form action the value"/reg_done", that's it.

Below is my views.py

```
        from django.shortcuts import render
        from django.http import HttpResponse
        import sqlite3
    
        # Create your views here.
        def Index(request):
            return render(request, 'index.html')
    
        def register(request):
            return render(request, 'register.html')
    
        def login(request):
             return render(request, 'login.html')
    
        def reg_done(request):
             name = request.POST.get('name')
             mail = request.POST.get('mail')
             phone = request.POST.get('phone')
             psw = request.POST.get('psw')
             pswr = request.POST.get('pswr')
             all = [name, mail, phone, psw, pswr]
             return render(request, 'reg_done.html', {'all':all})
```

Comment: Well the url does not make much sense, it should be `127.0.0.1:8000/register/reg_done/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the `register` view handles the registration. In the form for the `register.html` file,
Do:

```
<form action="/register/reg_done" method="post">
    your form fields here
</form>
```

if you want to go with pure HTML solution. If you want something more Django-ly, use the `url` template tag:

```
<form action="{% url 'reg_done' %}"  method="post">
    your form fields here
</form>
```

I'll advice the later to ensure you avoid "premium developer tears".

In `views.py`, add this to the top of the file:
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

Then edit the `reg_done` view to:

```py
@require_POST
def reg_done(request):
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    mail = request.POST.get('mail')
    phone = request.POST.get('phone')
    psw = request.POST.get('psw')
    pswr = request.POST.get('pswr')
    all = [name, mail, phone, psw, pswr]
    return render(request, 'reg_done.html', {'all':all})
```

Next, change the path for `reg_done` in `urls.py` to:
path('register/reg_done/', views.reg_done, name='reg_done'),

The problem lies in your usage of urls. You should reference the `reg_done` view as `/register/reg_done` instead of `register/reg_done`. The former treats it as an url relative to the domain name while the latter treats it as relative to the current page. That's why coming from the `register` view and going to the latter yields `register/register/reg_done` rather than what you want: `register/reg_done`.

Comment: I just edited the answer up there. Add a comment if you still encounter issues.